# Django stops with "generator raised StopIteration" when html form allows for file upload

Tags: python, html, django, apache

My setup is Windows 10, Python 3.7, Apache 2.4/mod_wsgi. When I add this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my form (just by adding this attribute, only -- no files are attached to the form) I get this error when submitting:

```
Django Version: 1.8.5
Exception Type: RuntimeError
Exception Value: generator raised StopIteration
Exception Location: c:\users\holistic\envs\vitadmin\lib\site-packages\django\http\multipartparser.py in read, line 337
Python Executable: C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
```

My Django code is this:

```
elif request.method == "POST":
    rid = request.POST.get("recipe", "")
    title = request.POST.get("title")
    content = request.POST.get("content")
    tag_names = request.POST.getlist("tags")
    image = request.FILES.get("image")
    if rid:
        recipe = get_object_or_404(FoodRecipe, pk=rid)
    else:
        recipe = FoodRecipe.objects.create(title=title)
    recipe.content = content
    recipe.title = title
    if image:
        recipe.featured = image
    for tn in tag_names:
        tag, cr = Tag.objects.get_or_create(
            name=tn
        )
        recipe.tags.add(tag)
    recipe.save()
```

And this is full traceback:

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.1.250/recipes/add/
Django Version: 1.8.5
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'tinymce',
 'sekizai',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'recipes',
 'guides',
 'inbox',
 'appdata',
 'account',
 'customer',
 'core')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'account.middleware.PasswordChangeMiddleware.PasswordChangeMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "c:\users\holistic\envs\vitadmin\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  125.                     response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
File "c:\users\holistic\envs\vitadmin\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\csrf.py" in process_view
  174.                     request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')
File "c:\users\holistic\envs\vitadmin\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py" in _get_post
  137.             self._load_post_and_files()
File "c:\users\holistic\envs\vitadmin\lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py" in _load_post_and_files
  260.                 self._post, self._files = self.parse_file_upload(self.META, data)
File "c:\users\holistic\envs\vitadmin\lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py" in parse_file_upload
  225.         return parser.parse()
File "c:\users\holistic\envs\vitadmin\lib\site-packages\django\http\multipartparser.py" in parse
  149.             for item_type, meta_data, field_stream in Parser(stream, self._boundary):
File "c:\users\holistic\envs\vitadmin\lib\site-packages\django\http\multipartparser.py" in __iter__
  628.             yield parse_boundary_stream(sub_stream, 1024)
File "c:\users\holistic\envs\vitadmin\lib\site-packages\django\http\multipartparser.py" in parse_boundary_stream
  567.     chunk = stream.read(max_header_size)
File "c:\users\holistic\envs\vitadmin\lib\site-packages\django\http\multipartparser.py" in read
  337.         out = b''.join(parts())

Exception Type: RuntimeError at /recipes/add/
Exception Value: generator raised StopIteration
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

PS: Same django application worked fine in Linux/Nginx/Gunicorn/Python2.7 setup. So, I guess it must some misconfiguration between Django/Python/Apache.

Comment: Please add your related code and the traceback to the question. No links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Django is very old and you need to update. This is a Python 3.7 compatibility problem that the Django devs already [fixed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/3f2de803181ca3c5526ec9d708b2098b8f683808) four years ago, back when it was just a PendingDeprecationWarning on Python 3.5.

In fact, you are on the very last Django version that doesn't have the fix. Even 1.8.6 has the fix.

Comment: Thanks. It is an old project that I had to migrate to a Windows setup for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, again for the version update. I stopped using 1.8 version of django long ago, but this was a legacy project that needed to be moved to a local server for some reason. I knew the problem was not in my code that is why I chose not to add the code and the full traceback information on this post (to keep it simple and easy to read). However, I still got downvoted for some reason.

Comment: Upgrading django to latest 1.8.19 fixes this issue! We just making migration from Django 1.7 to 1.8 in 2019 on live project! And i can tell that even Django 2 is not too far from 1.7 by features.