# Django Content Management System

Tags: python-3.x, django, content-management-system

When I try to add a new data in CMS of Django.
So I press the button, and then it shows me this.

```
RuntimeError at /admin/booktest/bookinfo/add/
generator raised StopIteration
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://../admin/booktest/bookinfo/add/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: RuntimeError
Exception Value:    
generator raised StopIteration
Exception Location: C:\Users\Nitro5\Desktop\pyango\lib\site-packages\django\http\multipartparser.py in read, line 337
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Nitro5\Desktop\pyango\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Nitro5\\Desktop\\pyango\\pyango\\test1',
 'C:\\Users\\Nitro5\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Nitro5\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Nitro5\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Nitro5\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Nitro5\\Desktop\\pyango',
 'C:\\Users\\Nitro5\\Desktop\\pyango\\lib\\site-packages']
```

And I went to the file 'multipartparser.py'.
I tried to add 'try-except StopIteration'.But it didn't work.
So....anyone can help?

Comment: Exactly what view is behind the `/admin/booktest/bookinfo/add/` url, can you [edit] the question and share that view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django stops with "generator raised StopIteration" when html form allows for file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197028/django-stops-with-generator-raised-stopiteration-when-html-form-allows-for-fil). It looks like you need to upgrade your django version.

Comment: Then I find out the problems. Version, the version I used about Django is 1.8.2, and the Python is 3.9.x. So I upgrade Django with lots of setting needed to be reset. And finally it worked.